# How can i add a custom View modifier for Shapes

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to call my ImageView with some kind of modifier to make the Image in it round or square. The code should look like:

```swift
ImageView(withURL: newsItem.imageUrl).test(Circle())
```

To get this behaviour i read you can extend the view like i did below. It works perfectly fine with a String but i don't understand what's different with a Shape?

I get the error Message **Protocol type 'Shape' cannot conform to 'Shape' because only concrete types can conform to protocols** but i don't understand that either :/. Can someone explain me the Problem and what i can do about it?

```swift
struct ImageView: View {
    var clipShape: Shape

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image("swift")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .clipShape(self.clipShape)
                .shadow(radius: 6)
        }
    }
}

extension ImageView {
    func test(_ shape: Shape) -> Self {
        var copy = self
        copy.clipShape = shape
        return copy
    }
}
```

btw this Code is shortened to only show the Code for the specific Problem, the View contains more than that. Just so you don't question the use of it.

Thanks in adnvance!

**EDIT:**

For why shapes don't work and what to do look at: https://forums.swift.org/t/how-to-make-different-clipshape/27448/2
In my Case if found out simply clipShaping the whole ImageView does the job just fine.
I also wanna link this [Creating custom modifiers for Swift UI views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56943036/creating-custom-modifiers-for-swift-ui-views) where you can read about custom modifiers

Answer (score 0):

I found this question while looking for the same title, but different intention - I want to create a modifier that can be applies specifically to something conforming to Shape so that I can do Shape like effects with it - stroke, etc.

But while I haven't found my answer yet, I think the answer to yours is that ViewModifier doesn't work to insert/change internal values of a view - instead you should be considering a ViewBuilder.

There aren't many articles that I've found really highlighting how to and when to effectively choose to use ViewBuilder, but this one from Majid entitled [The power of @ViewBuilder in SwiftUI](https://swiftwithmajid.com/2019/12/18/the-power-of-viewbuilder-in-swiftui/) does a pretty good job.
[Apple's docs on ViewBuilder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewbuilder) also (fortunately) include a bit of sample code in the reference (one of the few places for SwiftUI) that at least show you some basic ideas of how you can use it.

The basic gist is that ViewModifier always works in general with methods on View, where ViewBuilder is used as a means of *composing* views together, which sounds much more like what you want. In the end, they overlap significantly in what they can do - differing primarily in how they achieve it.

Answer (score -2):

Its a 3 step process:

1. Make a `ViewModifier`
2. Extend `View` with a function to apply your modifier and return the modified view
3. Call your modifying function on an actual `View`

```
struct RedBackGroundModifier: ViewModifier {
  func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    content.background(Color.red)
  }
}

extension View {
  func makeTheBackGroundRed() -> some View {
    self.modifier(RedBackGroundModifier())
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    Text("Hello, World!").makeTheBackGroundRed()
  }
}
```

Comment: You are not doing the same thing that i did. I want to apply the modifier to the whole View and then target the Image in it. You just put it on the Text directly. As i said my Code works with Strings, just not with the Shape protocol

Comment: Modifiers target the view they are attached to. The view protocol specifies that body is some View which means the type is opaque and you can not access its inner members. You can still target the clip to the enclosing view.

Comment: This doesn't really help me but i figured something out. I edited in the Question. Thanks anyway!