# Create View Function to Update Content of View

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm not sure how to word this, please bear with me.

I am trying to create a reusable view that will serve as a confirmation dialog. The dialog will be configurable, but I'd prefer not to pollute the initializer with every possible option. Instead, I'd like to have functions/modifiers that would be used post-initialization to update the view's content.

The following is my code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ConfirmationDialog: View {
    @Binding private var isPresented: Bool

    private var verb: String? = nil
    private var title: String? = nil
    private var text: String? = nil

    var confirm: () -> Void

    init(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, action confirm: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self._isPresented = isPresented
        self.confirm = confirm
    }

    public mutating func dialogVerb(_ verb: String) -> ConfirmationDialog {
        self.verb = verb
        return self
    }

    public mutating func dialogTitle(_ title: String) -> ConfirmationDialog {
        self.title = title
        return self
    }

    public mutating func dialogText(_ text: String) -> ConfirmationDialog {
        self.text = text
        return self
    }

    @Environment(\.backgroundColor) private var appBackgroundColor: Color
    @Environment(\.foregroundColor) private var appForegroundColor: Color

    var body: some View {
        OverlayView(toggle: $isPresented, backgroundColor: appBackgroundColor, cornerRadius: 0) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                if let verb = verb {
                    Text(verb)
                        .padding(top: 2, leading: 24, bottom: 2, trailing: 24)
                        .font(.callout)
                        .background(.blue)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4))
                }

                if let title = title {
                    Text(title)
                        .font(.title2)
                }

                if let text = text {
                    Text(text)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        .font(.body)
                        .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                        .lineLimit(2)
                        .padding(bottom: 32)
                }

                ConfirmDismissView(
                    confirmTitle: "Yes",
                    dismissTitle: "No",
                    confirmAction: {
                        confirm()

                        isPresented.toggle()
                    },
                    dismissAction: { isPresented.toggle() }
                )
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            .padding(32)
        }
    }
}

struct ConfirmationDialog_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ConfirmationDialog(isPresented: .constant(true)) {}
            .dialogVerb("Action")
            .dialogTitle("Delete Task")
            .dialogText("Are you sure you want to permanently delete this task?")
    }
}
```

But, I get the following error on each of my function calls:

> Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: function call returns immutable value

How would I create a view function that would modify the content of my view, similar to how `.navigationTitle()` works?

Comment: SwiftUI won't allow to mutate the properties of view in view block. So you need to create a new instance of view and change its properties as you wish. I believe this is the workaround to change its properties. You can prefer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56943847/11720834) to get the idea of how to update the properties of view. I hope it is what you seeking for

Comment: @Scotti that does work, thank you. Do you know if there are any consequences (or performance issues) for doing it this way? I guess I'm asking if this is the preferred way, or if there might be a better way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Look into view modifiers

Comment: @loremipsum I have. They apply to all views, and seem to only allow using other modifiers on the content as a whole. Or am I missing something?

Comment: As far as I know there will no performance issues regarding this because the way of modifiers working in SwiftUI replaces with a new one every time the value of modifiers changes. Of course, there are couple of way existed to inject the value into view using initializer or through environment values.

Answer (score 2):

You need to give the properties you're setting the @State attribute, which will update whatever views depend on it when changed:

```
@State private var verb: String? = nil
@State private var title: String? = nil
@State private var text: String? = nil
```

Then you don't need to make those functions mutating, since the @State vars by definition can mutate the View.

Another thing, as you mention the initializer, you can also give default values to init parameters to make them optional:

```
init(isPresented: Binding<Bool>,
     verb: String? = nil,
     title: String? = nil,
     text: String? = nil,
     action confirm: @escaping () -> Void) {
    self._isPresented = isPresented
    self._verb = State(initialValue: verb)
    self._title = State(initialValue: title)
    self._text = State(initialValue: text)
    self.confirm = confirm
}
```